# Setting custom Alpha in pandas EWM function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to smooth the closing price with a customer alpha but it does not seem to work. I receive the following message below

```
raise ValueError("comass, span, halflife, and alpha "
ValueError: comass, span, halflife, and alpha are mutually exclusive
```

this is the code I am running

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

import pandas_datareader.data as webb

df = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', '2020-01-01', '2019-12-31')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df['ema'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=10, alpha=3.0,adjust=True).mean()
```

I tried researching the issue but could not find much on the topic

Thanks

Comment: just read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html): span and alpha are linked by span = 2 / alpha - 1. Besides, alpha can't be greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the `.evm()` is expecting either `span` or `alpha` but not both. Code below should work:

```
df['ema'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=10, adjust=True).mean()
```

or

```
df['ema'] = df['Close'].ewm(alpha=3.0,adjust=True).mean()
```